# ppp as a network switch

Tags: linux, networking, route, petalinux

I have two devices which uses petalinux as OS. They are custom devices to use on some projects.
Their purpose is to act as routers with cabled connection (not ethernet). Devices are connected with cable and with special protocol. So they can not use ethernet interface. I need them to act as a switch.

[image: Connection diagram]

Devices have WEB GUI to configure them. Also they listen some udp sockets and process data.
But I also want to transmit all Ethernet packets to other device. So far I tried this :

Device 1
IP : 10.0.0.4/24
IP forwarding enable
Route 192.168.0.0 via ppp0

Device 2
IP : 192.168.0.5
IP Forwarding enable
Route 10.0.0.0 via ppp0

This way devices have a connection and i can transmit packets to other side.
But I can not use other IP domains. Both devices need to act as a switch.
When I am connected to Device 1's network, I need to access Device 2's WEB GUI.

I could not figure out what kind a ip route I should use.

What could be the solution?

Comment: While there appears to be a dedicated protocol (PPP BCP - rfc 3518 which doesn't appear to have much support on Linux) the easiest could be tunnel ethernet frames over IP. Something like ethernet over gre over ip over ppp.